# MVVM Light toolkit and tombstoning a ViewModel

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have downloaded the Base15 build that have the ViewModelBase public constructor to bee able to tombstone my viewmodel. The problem now is that the ViewModelBase is inheriting NotifyPropertyChanged that has an protected constructor generating the error 
"System.Security.SecurityException: The type 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.NotifyPropertyChanged' cannot be deserialized in partial trust because it does not have a public parameterless constructor" 
Am I missing something?

Regards

Fredrik

Answer (score 2):

Crap, that is an oversight that will be corrected in the next drop. Sorry about that. Feel free to set the constructor of NotifyPropertyChanged to public, that should not play any role.

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: No problem Laurent....you are doing an amazing job. Keep it up :-). I didn´t know if it was a bug or not so I posted it here. Hope you didn´t mind. Regards Fredrik from sweden

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me which serializer you are using? The two I tested here worked fine. Thanks! Laurent